# Setting default config for Visual Graph in GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

Is it possible to set a custom advanced graph configuration as a default config to use upon clicking 'Visual Graph' button (e.g. from the 'Graph overview' sidebar) in GraphDB Free 8.4.1?

I have declared advanced configurations that are suitable for exploring my data, but they are only available through 'Visual Graph' menu. I would like to use them (at least one) also when switching to graph visualisation from the view of triples.

I haven't found such an option so far. A desperate move could be to rewrite the URL and manually add a fixed '?config=*my_config*' parameter, but I hope there is a better way do solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to configure the default queries through GDB Workbench, but what you can do is change the queries in the files in your GDB distribution directly. They are located in graphdb/graphdb-/lib/workbench/WEB-INF/lib/graphdb-framework-graph-explore-.jar/graph-explore-queries/.. resourceLinks.sparql is the query for links expansion.